# Can't get Tomcat to start server on my Struts 2 application

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2

I'm trying to run a *Very* basic Struts 2 application however I keep getting the following error in my log whenever I try to run the server:

```
Mar 22, 2013 12:09:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Users\DJ\Downloads\eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32\eclipse;
Mar 22, 2013 12:09:44 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:DDay' did not find a matching property.
Mar 22, 2013 12:09:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 22, 2013 12:09:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 22, 2013 12:09:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 939 ms
Mar 22, 2013 12:09:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 22, 2013 12:09:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.37
Mar 22, 2013 12:09:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4656)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5309)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Mar 22, 2013 12:09:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Mar 22, 2013 12:09:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/DDay] startup failed due to previous errors
Mar 22, 2013 12:09:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 22, 2013 12:09:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 22, 2013 12:09:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 601 ms
```

I've got all of the required .jars for a struts 2 application

commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar

commons-io-2.0.1.jar

commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

commons-logging-api.1.1.jar

freemarker-2.3.19.jar

ognl-3.0.6.jar

struts2-core-2.3.12.jar

xwork-core-2.3.12.jar

javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar

And here is my web.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_9" version="2.4">
<display-name>Struts2 Application</display-name>
<filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I've seen several posts here on the same error, but none of the solutions seem to be working. If it isn't the jars and isn't the `web.xml` file, what could it be?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Figured it out. For whatever reason, Tomcat just didn't like that the Jars were not in the webcontent/lib directory. I had them elsewhere.

Comment: Then, when the time limit allows self answer the question or delete since no one else is likely to answer, since it is resolved.

Comment: where were you putting them?!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Struts2 but...
...looking at this site: http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/search?search_type=class&java_class=org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
It seems that for that version of struts2 the class isn't in the struts2-core.jar

Try to use another version of struts2.

Comment: Of course it is: `$ jar tf struts2-core-2.3.12.jar | grep StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter >>> 
org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/ng/filter/StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.class`